# Adding a Proxy to Twillio

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, twilio

I need to use `twilio` on a code and I would like to know where or how, in the example below, do I add the `proxy` settings?

```py
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account SID from twilio.com/console
account_sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
# Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console
auth_token  = "your_auth_token"

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
    to="+15558675309", 
    from_="+15017250604",
    body="Hello from Python!")

print(message.sid)
```

Please advise.

Comment: Clarify proxy. What are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Where do I add the proxy server address.

Comment: This? https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python/custom-http-clients-python